# Transposing rows into columns in view

Tags: sql-server

I have the following tables: `Dates` and `Transactions`

Dates

```
ID | Date      | DayOfQuarter
--------------------------------
1  | 1/1/2018  | 1
--------------------------------
2  | 1/2/2018  | 2
```

Transactions

```
ID | DateID | Type | Amount
-----------------------------
1  | 1      | 1    | 123.25
-----------------------------
2  | 1      | 2    | 456.58
-----------------------------
3  | 2      | 1    | 789.85
-----------------------------
4  | 2      | 2    | 987.96
-----------------------------
```

I want to transpose my `Type` Column into individual columns for a view to look as such

```
Date     | DayOfQuarter  |  Type1  |  Type2
----------------------------------------------
1/1/2018 |  1            |  123.25  | 456.58
----------------------------------------------
1/2/2018 |  2            |  789.85  | 987.96
```

Is there a way to do this? I've tried this so far, but not sure if there's a way to transpose the Type column

```
SELECT ddate.*, <Not sure at all>
FROM Transactions tran
LEFT JOIN Dates ddate ON tran.DateID = ddate.ID
```

For now, this will be a static set of transposed columns

Comment: if you have dynamic types then use `PIVOT` otherwise use `case statement` for type 1 and 2

Comment: [Dynamic Pivot](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2783/script-to-create-dynamic-pivot-queries-in-sql-server/), as @maSTAShuFu stated since I'm sure you have more than 2 types. You'll just want to concat the word [Type] to it

Comment: If this needs to be dynamic you will have find another solution than a view. You can't use dynamic sql or have a dynamic number of columns in a view.

Comment: It doesn't need to be dynamic. For now it's going to be static

Comment: Points: A) Views cannot be dynamic, and B) Views must have a fixed column-set(number, name and type) defined ahead of time.  As long as you can meet these requirements, then it can probably be done, otherwise there's no way.

Answer (score 1):

Since you stated it can be static... you can use `CASE`

```
select
   [Date]
    ,DayOfQuarter = DateID
    ,Type1 = Sum(case when Type = 1 then Amount else 0 end)
    ,Type2 = Sum(case when Type = 2 then Amount else 0 end)
from Transactions tran
LEFT JOIN Dates ddate ON tran.DateID = ddate.ID
group by [Date], DateID
```

Answer (score 0):

Using PIVOT syntax, you can do like below:

<kbd>**[See live demo](http://rextester.com/BOX22446)**</kbd>

```
select 
    [Date],
    [Dayofquarter],
    [type1]=MAX([1]),
    [type2]=MAX([2]) 
from 
(
    select 
        d.[Date],
        d.[Dayofquarter],
        t.*
    from dates d
    join transactions t
    on d.id=t.dateid
)src
pivot
(
    max(amount) for type in ([1],[2])
 )p
group by [Date],[Dayofquarter]
```